# Getting Google Shopping Categories from Big Commerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a way to get the google shopping categories via the API from the categories that have already been mapped?
If not can they be exported?

Once/If i get the google shopping categories what is the way to PUT the data into BigC via the API? I have been to the documentation but its almost empty.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/google_product_search_mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can only GET Google Shopping Data from specific products by ID. You cannot PUT any of that info, but it can be imported or exported through a CSV.

To see what commands are available with a given API endpoint, I'd direct you to look at the Resource page as opposed to the Object page. The Object page only gives definitions for the values that a given endpoint will return or request.

[More info on enabling Google Shopping in BigCommerce](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Selling-on-Google-Shopping/)

[Resource page for GPS](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/googleproductsearch)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.